# ¿Por qué siempre mi código no funciona y por qué me dice siempre que gane puntos?

Tags: javascript

```
let again

do {

let name = prompt('Antes de iniciar, ¿Cómo te llamas?')

alert(name+', la primera categoría es Entretenimiento')
let entretenimiento1 = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
if(entretenimiento1 == '100'){
    let entretenimiento100 = prompt ('¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)')
    if (entretenimiento100 == 1 ){
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')

    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '200'){
    let entretenimiento200 = prompt ('¿Cómo se llama el personaje de la mejor amiga de Mia Thermopolis en la película "El Diario de la Princesa"? Lilly, Emma, Anna, Bonny (Responde 1,2,3 o 4    ')
    if (entretenimiento200 = 1 ){
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')  
    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '300'){
    let entretenimiento300 = prompt (' ¿Quién es la artista más joven en ganar un premio Country?  Dolly Parton, Miley Cyrus, Taylor Swift, Carrie Underwood (Responde 1, 2, 3, 4)    ')
    if (entretenimiento300 = 3 ){
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '400'){
    let entretenimiento400 = prompt (' ¿Quién es el creador del talent show "The X Factor"? Louis Walsh, Simon Cowell, Sharon Osbourne, Nicole Scherzinger   ')
    if (entretenimiento400 = '2 ){
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '500'){
    let entretenimiento500 = prompt (' ¿En qué año se estrenó la película de Disney "Pinocho"? 1940, 1944, 1930, 1960    ')
    if (entretenimiento500 = '1' ){
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
    }
}else{
    alert('Opción no válida, el juego se reiniciará')
}
again = confirm('¿Quiéres volver a jugar?')
} while (again)
```

Estoy programando un juego tipo preguntados y se supone que cuando eligen la opción correcta debe decir "ganaste tales puntos" o algo así. Pero incluso cuando la respuesta está mal sigue diciendo ganaste tales puntos. Con el único que funciona es con la primera pregunta pero con las otras no.

Comment: Es porque dentro de los if pones un único igual, que en programacion significa asignar. En las comparaciones debes utilizar dos iguales seguidos == para comparar valores.

Comment: Por otra parte tienes un error en la línea del if entretenimiento400, pones una comilla que no va ahí.

Comment: Error de sintaxis a la vista: `if (entretenimiento400 = '2 ){`, falta una `'` que cierre el `2`

Comment: gracias a todos, haré todo!!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas otra variable para ir acumulando los puntos.  Ademas yo sacaria la primera pregunta fuera del bucle.  Algo asi:

```js
let again
let puntos = 0;

let name = prompt('Antes de iniciar, ¿Cómo te llamas?')

alert(name+', la primera categoría es Entretenimiento')

do {

let entretenimiento1 = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
if(entretenimiento1 == '100'){
    let entretenimiento100 = prompt ('¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)')
    if (entretenimiento100 == 1 ){
        puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.')

    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '200'){
    let entretenimiento200 = prompt ('¿Cómo se llama el personaje de la mejor amiga de Mia Thermopolis en la película "El Diario de la Princesa"? Lilly, Emma, Anna, Bonny (Responde 1,2,3 o 4    ')
    if (entretenimiento200 == 1 ){
        puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.')  
    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '300'){
    let entretenimiento300 = prompt (' ¿Quién es la artista más joven en ganar un premio Country?  Dolly Parton, Miley Cyrus, Taylor Swift, Carrie Underwood (Responde 1, 2, 3, 4)    ')
    if (entretenimiento300 == 3 ){
        puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.')
    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '400'){
    let entretenimiento400 = prompt (' ¿Quién es el creador del talent show "The X Factor"? Louis Walsh, Simon Cowell, Sharon Osbourne, Nicole Scherzinger   ')
    if (entretenimiento400 == '2' ){
        puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.')
    }
}else if(entretenimiento1 == '500'){
    let entretenimiento500 = prompt (' ¿En qué año se estrenó la película de Disney "Pinocho"? 1940, 1944, 1930, 1960    ')
    if (entretenimiento500 == '1' ){
        puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
        alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.')
    }
}else{
    alert('Opción no válida, el juego se reiniciará')
}
again = confirm('¿Quiéres volver a jugar?')
} while (again)
```

Comment: Yo trabajaría con una estructura de datos, un array o un json por ejemplo.

Comment: muchas graciaaas

Comment: @alanfcm no entiendo bien que es esto ||    puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1)          entendí que es para que se pueda llevar la sumatoria total de puntos pero no entiendo porque dice "+="  y que es parselnt

Comment: El `+=` es equivalente a decir `puntos = puntos + parseInt(entretenimiento1)`.  El `parseInt` es necesario porque el valor de la variable es de tipo `string` y esa funcion toma el valor y lo convierte a `integer`

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría esto con una estructura de datos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo basado en un JSON, por simplicidad he puesto sólo las dos primeras preguntas. Cualquiera de las dos que sea elegida mostrará la pregunta, el mensaje de éxito o de error y si es correcta la respuesta meterá los puntos que corresponda en un array.

He usado en casi todo la consola, si te interesa explorar esa posibilidad lo podrás adaptar sin mayor dificultad. Una de las ventajas aquí es que si en un futuro hubiera más preguntas sólo tienes que agregarlas al JSON y listo.

En lo que sería adaptación del código sería interesante un array de preguntas e ir controlando aquellas que ya fueron hechas para que no aparezcan de nuevo en el prompt. Y, como al parecer es un cuestionario por categorías puedes agrupar las preguntas por cada categoría y en base a eso ir mostrando las distintas preguntas que se hayan elegido, etc. Todo estaría expresado en el JSON y luego con unas 8 líneas de código manejas todo. Es mucho más simple que tener tantos `if elseif` como preguntas haya, en un cuestionario de 20 o 30 preguntas estaríamos hablando de un código kilométrico y poco portable.

Es sólo una propuesta, que espero te sea de ayuda.

```js
var mQuestions = `
{
   "questions":{
      "100":{
         "q":"¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)",
         "r":1
      },
      "200":{
         "q":"¿Cómo se llama el personaje de la mejor amiga de Mia Thermopolis en la película 'El Diario de la Princesa'? Lilly, Emma, Anna, Bonny (Responde 1,2,3 o 4",
         "r":1
      }
   },
   "messages":{
      "0":"Oh no, respuesta incorrecta... prepáralo mejor la próxima vez. No has acumlado puntos",
      "1":"¡Felicidades has respondido correctamente a la pregunta. Puntos acumulados "
   }
}
`;
var mJson = JSON.parse(mQuestions);
var allQuestions = mJson.questions;
var statusText = mJson.messages;
var mCounter = [];

let name="Pepe";
let e1 = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
var msg = "";
if (allQuestions.hasOwnProperty(e1)) {
  let v = prompt(allQuestions[e1].q);
  (allQuestions[e1].r == v) ? (msg = `${statusText[1]}: ${e1}`, mCounter.push(e1)) : (msg = statusText["0"]);
  console.log(mCounter);
  console.log(`${name} ${msg}`);
}
```

Comment: la verdad no entendí muy bien que es JSON o como leerlo pero igual muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @Fernanda un JSON es un archivo organizado por pares clave:valor. La organización se puede hacer por varios niveles. Aquí el JSON organiza en un nodo `questions` todas tus preguntas. Por conveniencia hay nodos `100`, `200` que sirven para identificar lo que preguntas en el prompt y dentro de cada uno una clave `q` que tiene el texto de la pregunta y una clave `r` que tiene la respuesta correcta. El código usa la estructura del JSON para preguntar, decidir si la respuesta es correcta y si lo es agregar los puntos correspondientes en un array. La ventaja es que ...

Comment: ... con las 6 líneas de código del bloque `if` podrás manejar todas las preguntas / respuestas sin tener que complicarte con tantos  `if ... elseif...` En un cuestionario con más de 10 preguntas tantos `if` sería un código extenso, no digamos nada si son 20 ò 30 ó 100 preguntas o más. Además, si hay que incorporar nuevas preguntas sólo las agregas al JSON y no hay que modificar nada en el código.